# Facebook Tagging friends to the picture

Tags: php, facebook, api, tags

Below code tag only first uid then then its shows **Fatal error**:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter and  can i use exact location for tagging.. as in below code x and y values are in pixel

```
$facebook = new Facebook ( array (
        'appId' => FBAPPID,
        'secret' => FBSECRETID 
) );
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport ( true );
if (isset ( $_POST ['image'] ) && isset ( $_POST ['tname'] )) {

    $path_to_image = encrypt::instance ()->decode ( $_POST ['image'] );
    $tags = (array)encrypt::instance ()->decode ( $_POST ['tname'] );
    /*
     * Output
     $tags = array (
            0 => '[{"tag_uid":"100001083191675","x":100,"y":100},{"tag_uid":"100001713817872","x":100,"y":230},{"tag_uid":"100000949945144","x":100,"y":360},{"tag_uid":"100001427144227","x":230,"y":100},{"tag_uid":"100000643504257","x":230,"y":230},{"tag_uid":"100001155130231","x":230,"y":360}]' 
        );
     */

    $args = array (
            'message' => 'Von ',
            'source' => '@' . $path_to_image,
            'access_token' => $this->user->fbtoken 
    )
    ;
    $photo = $facebook->api ( $this->user->data->fbid . '/photos', 'post', $args ); // upload works but not tags

    if (is_array ( $photo ) && ! empty ( $photo ['id'] )) {
        echo 'Photo uploaded. Check it on Graph API Explorer. ID: ' . $photo ['id'];
        foreach ( $tags as $key => $t ) {
            $tagRe = json_encode ( $t );
            $args = array (
                    'tags' => $tagRe,
                    'access_token' => $this->user->fbtoken 
            );
            $facebook->api ( '/' . $photo ['id'] . '/tags', 'post', $args );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer this link. It will be helpful for you. [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833253/simple-image-tagging-page-like-facebook-image-tag/23129551#23129551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing i dont get.

You `foreach` the tags as t right?
And in the `foreach` you pass it again in an `array`? than you `encode` it? why?

And the second please provide a bit more details and code.

I can only help you this way with these details.

if you place the folowing code.

```
foreach ( $tags as $t ) {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r(json_encode($t));
    }
```

you will get the following result

```
// encoded to json
{"tag_uid":"100001701664011","x":100,"y":100}
{"tag_uid":"100001726935992","x":100,"y":230}
{"tag_uid":"100001628449733","x":100,"y":360}
{"tag_uid":"100001286641924","x":230,"y":100}
{"tag_uid":"100001785887853","x":230,"y":230}
```

so you only need to do this

```
foreach ( $tags as $t ) {
       $tagRes = json_encode($t);
    }
```

just pass the t in a variable and encode it there.

Please provide more code

Comment: i have added more code has you requested... tags thing is not working