# How To Tag User's Friend In Uploaded Photo With Facebook Graph Api Php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I Am Using This Code But Getting Error: (wrong parameters)

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser(); 

      $friends = $facebook->api('/' . $uid . '/friends?limit=1');

    $tags[] = array('tag_uid' => $friends['data']['id'],
     'x' => '10',
     'y' => '10',
     );
```

i Want To tag any of the user's friend in uploaded photo. for this i should have uid of a friend so i m using `$friends['data']['id']` to get uid but it is not a valid parameter.

Help Me Out

Thanx

Comment: provide more code please, and take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543810/facebook-tagging-friends-to-the-picture/12543995#12543995 it is similar a bit what you would like, maybe it helps

Comment: all i want is user's friend's ID...... and in that example uid is given but i want to get user's friend's id....

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your app have the publish_stream permission on the user's account

to tag friends, you can invoke the tags connection of the photo you want to tag using the POST method. The "tags" argument should be an array of tag objects

Here's an example :

```
<photo_id>/tags=[{id:123,tag_text:friend1,x:10,y:20},{id:456,tag_text:friend2}]
```

Note that the coordinates are not mandatory.

Please note also that This feature is intended to help users tag their friends in real photos. Facebook may disable this feature for your application if it encourages tagging people on photos on wich they aren't

Comment: yeah i have publish_stream permissions. read my question again i want user's friend's ID to tag.

Comment: Indeed, my answer's is not relevant :-/. However, if you try to var_dump the $friend array (or echo json_encode($friends)), you will get the response structure. I'm not perfectly sure, but you may have the response data direclty (without the ['data'])